# Ajax requests to remote server on phonegap / local jquery or sencha

Tags: jquery, cordova, extjs

```
Mobile Device(file://..)                      Server

index.html                     <--JSON---   post.php
main.js
sencha_.js or Jquery_.js
```

The situation is like above,
All files (js,html) is on the mobile device by PhoneGap.(file://.../www/index.html...)
It will be showed by WebView.

and  main.js will call $.ajax() or Ext.Ajax.request() to receive json data from server. (whatever POST/GET)

is it possible? is there cross-domain problem?

Comment: yes. But only by using jsonp - witch isn't really an ajax call.

Comment: thanks. phonegap doesn't care about cross-domain

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible. Since your PhoneGap application is running from the file:// protocol the same origin policy does not apply, that is, no cross domain issues.

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap allows to do requests to any server, you don't need to use any hacky solutions, it just works, as long as you have the following line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but not using native AJAX methods.

One of the ways to make cross browser connections is to make a `script` tag and parsing all parameters to it via with a callback method: `GET only`

```
var url = "http://myPage.com/service.php?parem1=abc&parem2=def&callback=MY_CALLBACK";

window.MY_CALLBACK = function( response ) {
    // Here response have all your data.
}

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

**http://myPage.com/service.php**

```
<?
    Doing a lot of server site code...

    echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . $dataToPass . ");";
?>
```

`$_GET["callback"]` is `MY_CALLBACK` witch is our javascript method in the global scope.

Hope you can get the idea.

If you are using a framework i think almost all of then have a method to do this.

**jQuery**

```
var url = "http://myPage.com/service.php?parem1=abc&parem2=def";
$.ajax({
    "url": url,
    "dataType": "jsonp",
    "success": function(response) {
        // Here response have all your data.
    }
});
```

but you have no error handler :(

You use the plugin [jQuery.jsonp](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/) to get an error handler: From: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/wiki/TipsAndTricks

```
$.jsonp({
  "url": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+userId+"?callback=?",
  "data": {
      "alt": "json-in-script"
  },
  "success": function(userProfile) {
      // handle user profile here 
  },
  "error": function(d,msg) {
      alert("Could not find user "+userId);
  }
});
```